# How should we deal with "Good sources for ..." or "Where I can find ..." type of questions?

Tags: discussion

There are already quite a few question asking for resources, which basically ask for links:

- [Where are some good places to find free stock images?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/115/where-are-some-good-places-to-find-free-stock-images)
- [What are good sources for Open-Source fonts?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/280/what-are-good-sources-for-open-source-fonts)
- [Where can I find good filigree?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/270/where-can-i-find-good-filigree)
- [Where can I find tutorials for Gimp?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/131/where-can-i-find-tutorials-for-gimp)
- [Where can I find tutorials for Inkscape?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/132/where-can-i-find-tutorials-for-inkscape)

Should they be regular questions or community wikis, with one resource/answer?

(I tried a different approach in the [filigree](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/270/where-can-i-find-good-filigree) question, where I started a community wiki -answer to a regular question)

Should they (ever) be marked as "answered"?

Where should we draw the line; e.g. if someone would've asked for vector stock resources, should a question asking for filigree vectors be closed and pointed to the vector stock question?

---

*I know one can't mark their question as a community wiki, but needs to flag it for moderator attention.*

Answer (score 6):

I vote to mark them as `community wiki` and let the threads fall where they may. Broad or subjective does not always equal bad.

Comment: Only admins can make questions community wiki these days

Answer (score 6):

Some amount of "List of X" questions is bound to pop up, and it's not a bad thing IMO because the community pours all its current knowledge of "where to get xyz" into them.

As long as they don't become too subjective or too esoteric, I am in favour of letting them live as Community Wiki.

Related discussion on Meta.SO: [Should we have a “List of X” close reason?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57226/should-we-have-a-list-of-x-close-reason)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Discussion is always good. If we limit discussion, discussion may die down slowly in the future and SE GD might get closed.